# Check if string is UTF-8 returning \u+hex if so, false if not

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, hex, typechecking

For [XSS safety](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22273848/1382306), I'd like to convert all characters to \u+hex encoding.  I've seen [UTF-16 solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786516/1382306), but I can't find anything for UTF-8.

I first want to ensure that all characters are UTF-8.  Here, I've seen many solutions but nothing consistent for javascript.

How can a string be tested for UTF-8 and return the \u+hex encoding if so yet false if not?

Comment: I 'm not so sure if you understand the implications here. How is ensuring that the input is UTF-8 going to protect you from injections? In that other question you say "I want to inject stuff *anywhere*" -- frankly, doing that safely is borderline (and in practical terms, probably crossing into) impossible.

Comment: A string, in JS, is made of characters, not bytes. Characters are a purely notional thing, whereas bytes are the numbers that get physically stored on a disk or transmitted over a wire. That means, there is no encoding as far as the programmer is concerned. You can not test a string for encoding.

Comment: @Gracchus: Perhaps I 'm not getting the point correctly, but all of this sounds very misguided. If you inject HTML content you need to turn special characters into HTML entities; if the content is inside an open tag or attribute value you further need to prevent scripting attacks, etc. None of this is going to be prevented by encoding checks.

Comment: @Gracchus: I get the feeling I don't really understand your question. Perhaps you should provide more context, i.e. where do your strings come from and where should they go to. Also, who is Brian McGinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function string_to_hex(input) {
    var temp = 0, output = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        temp = input.charCodeAt(i);
        if (temp > 0xFF) {
//      if (temp == 192 || temp == 193 || temp > 244) {
            return false;
        }
        output += "\\x" + temp.toString(16).slice(1); //lazy padding
    }
    return output;
}
```

The line commented out isn't needed if you do not check for illegal code points.